# SEO plugin fails on recent updates

Tags: craft3, plugin-seo

The upgrade logs for ethercreative/seo says to backup before upgrading, but gives no explaination on how to fix the issues if you get them.

```
bash-4.4# ./craft  seo/upgrade/to-new-data-format
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `el`.`type`, `el`.`id`, `fields`.`handle`
FROM `craft_fields` `fields`
INNER JOIN `craft_fieldlayoutfields` `flf` ON `flf`.`fieldId` = `fields`.`id`
INNER JOIN `craft_fieldlayouts` `fl` ON `fl`.`id` = `flf`.`layoutId`
INNER JOIN `craft_elements` `el` ON `el`.`fieldLayoutId` = `flf`.`layoutId` AND `el`.`type` = `fl`.`type`
WHERE `fields`.`type`='ether\\seo\\fields\\SeoField''

in /var/www/codebase/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:664

Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1267
    [2] => Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
)
```

Is this an issue anyone knows how to fix?

Comment: Note that it is less the upgrade to db that I'm worried about, more the fact that when I put it live the whole site broke!

Comment: Difficult to know if this is a bug in the plugin, or something database specific. What charset/collation is your database set to by default and have any tables/columns been changed from that default? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic